# how to use the physical device to test ads [Android]

Tags: android, android-studio, ads

After the change of the version of google services ads, the addTestDevice option no longer appears, how can I see bonus videos on a physical device?

```
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                      //  Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                        mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow steps [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433?hl=en)

> Add a test device To make changes to a test device, such as enabling
> or changing ad inspector gestures, you’ll need to remove the test
> device and set it up again. Sign in to your AdMob account at
> https://apps.admob.com.
>
> Click Settings in the sidebar.
>
> Click the Test devices tab.
>
> Click Add test device.
>
> Select the platform of your device.
>
> Enter a device name. Consider using a name that will help you quickly
> identify your devices in your AdMob account.
>
> Note: The device name will be visible to anyone who has access to your
> AdMob account.
>
> Enter your Advertising ID/IDFA. Learn how to find your advertising
> ID/IDFA.
>
> Select a gesture to use to activate ad inspector:
>
> None.  If you select none, you can still activate ad inspector with an
> API call. Learn more.
>
> Shake
>
> Flick twice
>
> Click Done.